# Pyspark apply udf to add a new col, but the the number of rows is not correspond

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have a dataframe, which one column 'topic1' is a type of structure and another one 'topic' is string, i want to extract the value of 'topic1' according to column 'topic' use the udf. But something goes wrong because the number of dataframe is  mismatch.

```
def mapExtr_miss(map_var, key, miss_num): 
    try:
        if key and str(key) in map_var.keys() and len(map_var[str(key)])>0:
            return map_var[str(key)]
    except:
        return [0]*miss_num

def udf_Extr_miss(miss_num):
return udf(lambda map_var, key: mapExtr_miss(map_var, key, miss_num), ArrayType(IntergType()))
```

the results as follows:

```
c1 = combine.withColumn('topic2', udf_Extr_miss(198)(col('topic1'), col('topic')))
c1.count()
266132                                                                          
combine.count()
271997                                                                          
c2= combine.withColumn('topic2', udf_Extr_miss(41)(col('topic1'), col('topic')))
c2.count()
277497
```

thanks for any idea about this problem

```
c1.head(n=2)

[Row(uid=u'u1', newsid=u'451', topic1=Row(98=None, 99=None, 9999=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1212, 1212, 1212, 1212, 1212, 1212, 1, 1, 1, 500, 0]),  topic=None, heat=0.5841230154037476, jumpLink=0, topic2=None),Row(uid=u'u822316', newsid=u'4514', topic1=Row(98=None, 99=None, 9999=[1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1212, 1212, 1212, 1212, 1212, 1212, 1, 1, 1, 500, 0]),  topic='9999', heat=0.5841230154037476, jumpLink=0, topic2=[1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1212, 1212, 1212, 1212, 1212, 1212, 1, 1, 1, 500, 0])]
```

Comment: can you please share example data and expected output?

Comment: example data as follows:  Row(uid=u'u1', newsid=u'451', topic1=Row(98=None, 99=None, 9999=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1212, 1212, 1212, 1212, 1212, 1212, 1, 1, 1, 500, 0]),  topic=None, heat=0.5841230154037476, jumpLink=0, topic2=None)

Comment: can you please edit that into the post?

Comment: sorry, first time to ask question and newer of using pyspark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw some defects with your `udf` function as `map_var.keys()` always *throws exception* and the `udf` function behaves randomly. Please use the following `udf` function and you should be fine

```
def mapExtr_miss(map_var, key, miss_num):
    try:
        return map_var[str(key)]
    except:
        return [0]*miss_num

def udf_Extr_miss(miss_num):
    return udf(lambda map_var, key: mapExtr_miss(map_var, key, miss_num), ArrayType(IntegerType()))
```

Comment: hi, the different number of rows can info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49193614/pyspark-count-different-numbers-for-the-same-dataframe. Besides, your function is right

Comment: What do you want me to do with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49193614/pyspark-count-different-numbers-for-the-same-dataframe? the counts varies according to the transformation you did before count action. make sure the transformation that you applied is consistent with every action. and you should be fine

Comment: nothing to do. it just confused me long time, but i do not know how to add a new answer, so i reply it following you. Anyway, thanks you very much